# How to have enunciate generate documentation referencing existing xsd

Tags: java, xsd, maven-2, jax-rs, enunciate

I am using enunciate 2.6.0 to generate documentation for jax-rs services. For 1 method I am using a custom `MessageBodyWriter` to serialize to xml. I have an xsd file describing the response. Is it possible to point enunciate to that schema doc? By default, enunciate generates an ns0.xsd that is basically empty.

This [page](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Module-IDL) in the wiki seems describes the ability to configure existing schema. I have configured that so that it finds the local xsd file (the build fails if it cannot find it), but the generated documentation still does not reference it. I believe the problem is that there does not appear to be a tie from the object returned from the method and the xml type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the key is to use the default namespace in the [idl schema](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Module-IDL) configuration value, even though a "real" namespace is used at runtime.